# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint when INSERTing from a temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL (2012) table called [RlasRmSysUsers] and it has a super key of three different fields. I am trying to duplicate records, but save them back to the table with different IDs. I decided to create a temp table and fill it with the entries tied to a entered ID number. Then I change the ID number in the temp table, and finally I INSERT the temp table back into the original table. I can create, populate, and edit the temp table with no issues, but I get an error when I try to INSERT the temp table back into the main table. It says I violate the key and cancels the INSERT process. I check and the ID doesn't even exist in the original table yet. Ideas?

I create the new temp table-

```
SELECT  [UserID]
  ,[UserRoleID]
  ,[UserFinBlockCd]
  ,[UserAOR]
  ,[UserOrgID]
  ,[UserName]
  ,[UserStatus]
  ,[UserActiveProfile]
  ,[LastChangeDt]
  ,[LastChangeBy]
  into #TempRLAS FROM [RlasRmSysUsers] WHERE UserID='12345.tmp' and UserActiveProfile = 1
```

I update the temp table

```
UPDATE #TempRLAS SET UserID='998877.POS', UserName = '', [LastChangeDt]= GETDATE(), [LastChangeBy]='990011.me';
```

Finally I try to add it to the original table and then drop it

```
INSERT INTO [RlasRmSysUsers] SELECT * FROM #TempRLAS; 
DROP TABLE #TempRLAS;
```

table struct

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RlasRmSysUsers](
[UserID] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
[UserRoleID] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
[UserFinBlockCd] [char](4) NOT NULL,
[UserAOR] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
[UserOrgID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[UserName] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
[UserStatus] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[UserActiveProfile] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[LastChangeDt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[LastChangeBy] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_RlasRmSysUsers_UserID_UserRoleID_UserFinBlockCd] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[UserID] ASC,
[UserRoleID] ASC,
[UserFinBlockCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  =     ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What are the parts to your key?  I'm assuming your update statement is updating fields for some or all of the fields of your composite.  You would have to have some duplicates in there somewhere :P

Comment: What are the three fields that make up the key on the main table?

Comment: Please provide your RlasRmSysUsers table structure and index definitions.

Comment: [UserID] ,[UserRoleID]  ,[UserFinBlockCd]

Comment: The exact error I get is :

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_RlasRmSysUsers_UserID_UserRoleID_UserFinBlockCd'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RlasRmSysUsers'. The duplicate key value is (998877.POS, ADARS, ZZ00).

Comment: add the table struct to the bottom of the OP

Comment: You must already have records in your table with "998877.POS, ADARS, ZZ00", doing your statement to engineer records is causing overlap.

Comment: @J-Rivera, how many rows are in the temp table?

Comment: @AHiggins I run a select statement on the temp query just to see the result set of the temp and there is only 8 records and none of them violate the PK restrictions of the original table. In the example I set above, the 998877.POS is a new employee ID that's not in the original table while 'ADARS' is a role type and the 'ZZ00' is an job code.

Comment: It's possible for a user to have multiple entries in the table with different role types and job codes. I didn't develop this DB, but is now tasked with maintenance. The task called for adding a new Employee ID but having it copy all the entries of an existing employee. The previous victim would just write down all the info and enter a INSERT query for each entry. I am writting a stored Proc to make this task easier.

Comment: What happens if you create the same constraint on your temp table? Do any of the insert or update statements fail ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, mystery solved, sorta. I completely replaced the data and it worked. Not sure why. I returned back to the original addition and then it worked as well. *shrug*